# passing a list to Mapper and reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my hadoop application, before running job2, a function is run and its output is:    **List < IntArrayList > myList**  .    Mapper and Reducer in job2 need myList. How can I pass myList to mapper and reducer?

Comment: write this list records to a file and then pass the location of this input to your job. From there `Mapper` will parse it record by record and performs your business logic present in the `map()` implementation.

Comment: can I write  list records to a file in HDFS directly or I should write in a local file then copy local file into HDFS?

Comment: yes , you can write directly to a file on HDFS. But i would rather suggest to first write it in your local and then move it to HDFS.